# Max with inner join need more column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by, max, inner-join

Here is my query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.id_b = b.id
INNER JOIN d ON d.id_c = c.id
INNER JOIN e ON e.id = d.id_e
```

My problem is it returns some rows which are excatly the same except for the 'c' table values. I need to take the max of one column of 'c' but I don't know how exactly.

Example of what this query returns :

```
a.fields    b.fields   c.id   c.gamut   c.position    d.fields   e.fields
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ...         ...        1       2        1              ...        ...  
  ...         ...        2       2        2              ...        ...
  ...         ...        3       2        3              ...        ...
  ...         ...        4       3        1              ...        ...
  ...         ...        4       3        2              ...        ...
```

What i need to have :

```
a.fields    b.fields   c.id   c.gamut   c.position    d.fields   e.fields
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ...         ...        3       2        3              ...        ...
  ...         ...        4       3        2              ...        ...
```

I need to get the max position for the same gamut.

Information:

- '...' means the values for tables columns are the same for each rows by gamut

Comment: your question is not clear enough. Please be specific.

Comment: Don't forget that inner join without appropriate "where" clauses is not 1-1 relationship but 1-n, that's why you get copies of a,b and d fields. Please be more specific on what you are trying to achieve and provide some mock data.

Comment: In my query, i need for the 'c' table to get the max(position) by gamut. I don't know how to do this with inner joins. And in need to keep the c.id to join with the 'd' table.

Comment: Replace asterisk (*) with required field list and use aggregate functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple application of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
;WITH Ordered AS (
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.gamut ORDER BY c.position desc) as rn 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.id_b = b.id
INNER JOIN d ON d.id_c = c.id
INNER JOIN e ON e.id = d.id_e
)
select * from Ordered where rn = 1
```

(If there are multiple rows with the same max `Position` for the same `gamut`, this will select an arbitrary one. If there are further tie-breaking columns, add those to the `ORDER BY`. If you *want* the ties to show up, switch to `RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()`)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try this and let me know whether it is working or not, If not than please provide me the schema and data for tables

```
SELECT  a.fields,b.fields,max(c.id),c.gamut,max(c.position),d.fields,e.fields
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON b.id_a = a.id
INNER JOIN c ON c.id_b = b.id
INNER JOIN d ON d.id_c = c.id
INNER JOIN e ON e.id = d.id_e
group by a.fields,b.fields,c.gamut,d.fields,e.fields
```